# Karger's Algorithm - Running Time - Edge Contraction

Tags: adjacency-list, kargers-algorithm, contractions

In [Karger's Min-Cut Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karger%27s_algorithm) for undirected (possibly weighted) multigraphs, the main operation is to contract a randomly chosen edge and merge it's incident vertices into one metavertex. This process is repeated until two vertices remain. These vertices correspond to a cut. The algo can be implemented with an adjacency list.

Questions:

1. how can I find the particular edge, that has been chosen to be contracted?
2. how does an edge get contracted (in an unweighted and/or weighted graph)?
3. Why does this procedure take quadratic time?

Edit: I have found some information that the runtime can be quadratic, due to the fact that we have O(n-2) contractions of vertices and each contraction can take O(n) time. It would be great if somebody could explain me, why a contraction takes linear time in an adjacency list. Note a contraction consists of: deleting one adjacent edge, merging the two vertices into a supernode, and making sure that the remaining adjacent edges are connected to the supernode.

Pseudocode:

```
procedure contract(G=(V,E)):
while |V|>2
    choose edge uniformly at random
    contract its endpoints
    delete self loops
return cut
```

I have read the related topic [Karger Min cut algorithm running time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33486632/karger-min-cut-algorithm-running-time), but it did not help me. Also I do not have so much experience, so a "laymens" term explanation would be very much appreciated!